# Changing values in MongoDB with POST request - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular

I am attempting to make a post request which will replace a value in MongoDB.
The user enters a new value (bitcoin) into a form. Upon submitting the form, the post request is started:

```
  bitcoinChange(bitcoin){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/bitcoin', bitcoin, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

The post request finds the current user by their username, then changes their current bitcoin value (user.bitcoin) to the new value being submitted.

```
router.post('/bitcoin', (req, res, next) => {
    const bitcoin = req.body.bitcoin;

    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            return res.json({ success: false, msg: 'User not found.' })
        }

        User.changeBitcoin(bitcoin, user.bitcoin, () => {
            if (bitcoin = user.bitcoin) {
                res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Failed to change Bitcoin amount.' });
            } else {
                user.bitcoin = bitcoin;
                res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Bitcoin amount changed!' });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The changeBitcoin function:

```
// Takes in what user types as the new bitcoin value, sets current value to candidateBitcoin
module.exports.changeBitcoin = function(candidateBitcoin, callback){
    candidateBitcoin = User.bitcoin
    User.save(callback);
}
```

Is this the right way to go about a user changing a value in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Nope

```
router.post('/bitcoin', (req, res, next) => {
  const bitcoin = req.body.bitcoin;
  User.update({ username }, { $set: { bitcoin } })
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
    .catch(next);
});
```

Comment: Interesting, is that the only thing that needs to be changed? Or is everything I had after the post request redundant now?